# new operator omission in value type

Tags: c#, .net

Why do we not use the `new` operator with value type but not the rest for object construction?

Comment: There is no such `NEW` operator in the C# language. You probably meant the `new` operator which is used to invoke the object constructor. Is it what you meant?

Comment: Code please? It's not clear to me what you mean. You always have to create a `Something foo = new Something()` when you want to use it. If it gets written by a  function returning an object, or if you assign a value to it, you don't have to instantiate it using `new`, it can then be omitted.

Comment: new operator invoked for object construction, why we use one for reference type but not value type

Answer (score 5):

You can use `new` with value types, but the primitive value types like `int`, `float` and `bool` typically don't have anything other than the default constructor which gives you the default value for a given value type, so there isn't a point to doing so before assigning actual values (either obtained from method calls or by hardcoding literal values). This is why you rarely see `new` with primitive value types.

Structs like `Rect` have constructors with parameters which you can invoke on initialization using `new`, in the same way you initialize reference types:

```
var rect = new Rect(100, 100, 450, 240);
```

Structs are like classes, the only (and key) difference being that these are in fact value types. In fact, `int`, `float` and `bool` are all keywords corresponding to the `System.Int32`, `System.Single` and `System.Boolean` structs respectively.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you mean. For both reference types and value types, to initialize a variable to something explicitly, you have to specify a value. This value might be provided from:

- A property
- A method call
- The `default(...)` operator
- The `typeof(...)` operator
- A constructor call
- Another variable
- A method group conversion
- A literal
- The result of an operator (e.g. addition)

*All* of these apply to both reference types and value types (other than `typeof(...)` and method group conversions, as both of these are always reference type values).

For example:

```
// Assignment from a string literal - string is a reference type
string x = "hello";

// Assignment from the result of a constructor call - DateTime is a value type
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
```

Comment: I understand that `typeof(int) == typeof(int)` is always true, but could you elaborate on the term "reference type values"? Is it like string interning in any way?

Comment: @BoltClock: Both `Type` and `Delegate` are reference types, so there's no way that `typeof(...)` or a method group conversion can return a value of a value type.

Comment: new operator invoked for object construction, why we use one for reference type but not value type – Fad Eyi just now

Comment: @Fad Eyi: Your comment doesn't make much sense, I'm afraid - and I've shown in the answer how sometimes we *do* use the constructor for value type construction.